Definitions for hermitian manifolds
I've found two different ways of defining hermitian manifolds and wanted to know if these two are equivalent?
Let $X$ be a complex manifold, then $X$ is called hermitian if it has a hermitian metric on the holomorphic tangent bundle $T^{1,0}X$.
The other definition I have is that on a complex manifold $X$ a Riemannian metric $g$ is called a hermitian structure if for any $x \in X$, the scalar product $g_x$ on $T_x X$ is compatible with the canonical almost complex structure $I_x$. A complex manifold with an hermitian structure $g$ is called an hermitian manifold.
So at the moment these seem quite different to me. The first one considers the holomorphic tangent bundle and the latter the real bundle $TX$. I know that there is an isomorphism between these two, but still I find these definitions quite different.

Have you tried to work out why they’re equivalent? It’s a worthwhile exercise.

Is this the same thing that if I have a real vector space $(V,g,I)$ with an inner product and a almost complex structure then I can define a hermitian form by $h(x,y) = g(x,y) + g(x,Iy)$ on $(V,I)$? @Deane

At each point, yes. But there’s the additional condition that the almost complex structure is integrable

I see. I'm wondering about the fundamental form $\omega$ which should be the $g(x,Iy)$ in this case. Occasionally you see this written as $$\omega = \frac{i}{2} h_{ij}dz^i \wedge d\bar{z}^j,$$ but then sometimes its written with $g$ as $$\omega = ig_{ij}dz^i \wedge d\bar{z}^j.$$ Is there a distinction between these two or is this a convention related to what I'm asking about here? @Deane

Each is a $(1,1)$-tensor, i.e., a sesquilinear function of the complexified tangent space. So they're the same tensor if and only if they're equal as functions. You can check whether this is the case by feeding in any pair of complex tangent vectors or, more simply, any pair of basis vectors.

So if $\omega = \frac{i}{2} h_{ij}dz^i \wedge d\bar{z}^j,$ then this applied to the basis vectors give $$\omega(\partial/\partial z^k, \partial/\partial \bar{z}^l) = \frac{i}{2}h_{kl}.$$ If $\omega = ig_{ij}dz^i \wedge d\bar{z}^j$, then $$\omega(\partial/\partial z^k, \partial/\partial \bar{z}^l) = ig_{kl}.$$ So these two would be equal if we had the relationship $h_{kl}=2g_{kl}$? @Deane

Yup. Hermitian geometric formulas are full of powers of $i$, $2\pi$, and $2$, which can drive you nuts. There is no common convention on where to put these powers.
